# Synchronizing two databases via mappings in Python

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, data-migration

I have a live Django 1.6 project that makes use of a postgresql database. I've currently been developing an API for the project to support a mobile app - making use of South migrations as I go along.

As a result of the of this: I have a new database structure and code-base that is quite far removed from my production database although many of the fields in the production database are still present in the new one.

So as it sits - I have the mobile app running off the new API and the website running off the old database.

**How can I go about synchronizing data between the two databases while the front-end for the new website is being developed?**

*i.e. When a user makes use of the app and then later goes to the website, I'd like their data to be available and vice-versa.*

Solutions I've tried:

- I cannot use the API to update the new database because it would trigger activation emails for users that have already been activated.
- I've tried to use [peewee](http://peewee.readthedocs.org) to create a synchronization script where each field in one database is mapped to a field in the other database. This has been effective for tables where the schema are similar but I've had trouble when it comes to keeping foreign key relationships in tact.